# DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

Installed anaconda 3 with python 3.7.1 and extracted openCV 3.4.5. Copied and renamed the cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd file from opencv(python3.7 folder) as cv2.pyd and pasted on Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages.

Tried installing opencv through anaconda navigator; installed visual C++ redistributable; tried through opencv-contrib-python; checked if the python3.dll is missing, but present. And none of these helped.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-252459bf3e0b> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen some of these installation issues before and found the easiest solution to be pip. Instructions can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

If you already have pip installed, simply run `pip install opencv-python` from your command line. You may have to clean up some of your old installation attempts for this to work, but try it first and test it real quick with something like `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"`. You should get something like `4.0.0` as a response.